# .sql file failing to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in the final steps of submitting a lab for school with the final condition being I have to copy/paste all of my commands with the corresponding question into a sql file named 'lab2.sql'. I've done so but when I attempt to execute the file I receive the follow errors:

```
source lab2.sql
-bash: /*Name: No such file or directory : No such file or directory
-bash: /*Section:: No such file or directory
-bash: /*Lab: No such file or directory
-bash: /*Can: No such file or directory
-bash: /*Consequently,: No such file or directory
-bash: /*Is: No such file or directory
-bash: /*Use: No such file or directory
-bash: lab2.sql: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'bash: lab2.sql: line 12: `ALTER TABLE VENDOR ADD CONSTRAINT VENDOR_V_CODE_PK PRIMARY KEY (V_CODE);
```

Portion of the 'lab2.sql' file.

```
/*Name*/
/*student id*/
/*Section: B*/
/*Lab 2*/

/*Can the V_CODE column accept null values?: No*/
/*Consequently, is the product entity existence-dependent of the vendor entity?: Yes*/
/*Is the product entity optional to the Vendor entity?: Yes*/

/*Use alter command to add a primary key constraint on V_CODE of the vendor table. Name the constraint as VENDOR_V_CODE_PK: */

ALTER TABLE VENDOR ADD CONSTRAINT VENDOR_V_CODE_PK PRIMARY KEY (V_CODE);

/*Write a SQL command to create the product table (defined below) along with defining the constraints a, b, c and d.  Allow naming of the constraints for b) c) and d) where the */
/*constraint name should start with the table name, underscore, column name, underscore then the symbol for the constraint itself: */

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (P_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, P_DESCRIPT VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE, P_INDATE DATE NOT NULL, P_QOH INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (P_Id>0), P_MIN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (P_Id>0), P_PRICE NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL, P_DISCOUNT NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL, V_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

I apologize if this comes as a silly question. I am only beginning to use sql

Comment: you have tagged both mysql and sql (normally use for sql server), not 100% sure for sql server but for mysql when you run source lab2.sql you need to be doing that at the mysql prompt (i.e. within the mysql client), if you are running it at the shell itself that might generate the errors.

Comment: @Niagaradad thank you, this solved my problem